# ELM recursive iteration

Tags: algorithm, elm

I need to create a function that takes a number, such as for a given number x, it computes the number y, by adding all digits of number x to itself.

An example :

Given x = 123:
It return 129 = 1 + 2 + 3 + 123

Given x = 35:
It return y = 43 = 3 + 5 + 35

I have this function that works but I need another way:

```
computeNextValue : Int -> Int
computeNextValue input =
    String.fromInt input
        |> String.split ""
        |> List.filterMap String.toInt
        |> List.sum
        |> (+) input
```

Comment: Do not work on Strings. Conversion between integer and strings is a waste of computation. You can extract the digits by using `/` and  `%`.

Comment: @MrSmith42: except that this is exactly what the conversion does, probably in a faster way as it is built-in.

Comment: What do you mean you need another way? Why do you need another way? Do you have a specific requirement for the other way?

Comment: With only number, without to transform it in String

Answer (score 2):

First, let's make a recursive function that gives you all the digits of a number. The main idea is that you can get the rightmost digit of an integer by `modBy 10`, and you can remove it from the number by `// 10`:

```
getDigits : Int -> List Int 
getDigits num =
    if num == 0 then 
        [] -- base case
    else
        modBy 10 num :: getDigits (num // 10) -- recursive case
```

Note that this function returns the `[]` for `0`, but that's OK for this usecase.

```
computeNextValue : Int -> Int
computeNextValue input =
    input + List.sum (getDigits inputs)
```

Comment: `remainderBy` would probably be clearer & more correct than `modBy`, though they have the same effect for positive numbers: this is not modular arithmetics.